# MobX State Tree generator does not allow modified state in a successful promise?

Tags: generator, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

Via the code following I get this error:

```
error: Error: [mobx-state-tree] Cannot modify 
'AuthenticationStore@<root>', the object is protected and can only be 
modified by using an action.
```

the code (generator) in question:

```
.model('AuthenticationStore', {
    user: types.frozen(),
    loading: types.optional(types.boolean, false),
    error: types.frozen()
  })
  .actions(self => ({
    submitLogin: flow(function * (email, password) {
      self.error = undefined
      self.loading = true
      self.user = yield fetch('/api/sign_in', {
        method: 'post',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          'user' : {
            'email': email,
            'password': password
          }
        })
      }).then(res => {
        return res.json()
      }).then(response => {
        self.loading = false // the error happens here!
        return response.data
      }).catch(error => {
        console.error('error:', error)
        // self.error = error
      })
    }), ...
```

**The question:** is this not permitted in a generator, is there a better way to update this particular state or does it need to be wrapped by a try/catch?

As always **thanks is advance** for any and all feedback!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you're calling `then` on the Promise returned by `fetch()`, and the function you pass to `then` is not an action. Note that functions that run *within* an action (or flow) do not count as the action itself.

Since you're using `yield`, you don't need to call `then` or `catch` on the Promise returned by `fetch()`. Instead, wrap it in a try/catch:

```js
submitLogin: flow(function* (email, password) {
  self.error = undefined;
  self.loading = true;
  try {
    const res = yield fetch('/api/sign_in', {
        method: 'post',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          'user' : {
            'email': email,
            'password': password
          }
        })
    });
    const response = yield res.json();
    self.loading = false;
    self.user = response;
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('error: ', error);
    self.error = error;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense now that you point it out.  Possibly the reason none of my components with the injected store are not seeing the updates.  Thanks!